# Solr - search for all substrings of a given string

Tags: solr, fuzzy-search

If I have a given String "ABCDEF" how can I run a search so I can get all results where it found substrings such as "A", "EF" "CDE" "ABCDEF"

I'm having trouble using regex since searching for strings with some letters able to be missed is giving me results like "BDE" which is invalid because it is allowed to skip "C" in that case.

Comment: which queries did you try?

Comment: Have you tried using an NGramFilter?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What is the text you are indexing and trying to find (ABCDEF)? And what are the search strings you are searching with (A, EF, etc)?

Comment: @Mysterion So far I tried regex like "A?B?C?D?E?F?" to try and fetch the right things... Didn't get too far with that though. I know there's ways to generate a large regex which covers all possible iterations of substrings, but I want to hopefully avoid that mess

Comment: @MatsLindh This sort of looks like it might be the answer... Do you have any online tuts you would reccommed? I'm googling through and getting things like 'NGram tokenizer' as a result.. Am I in the right ballpark here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an NGramFilter (not tokenizer) in your analysis chain for the Text Field - it'll split the text into separate tokens for each substring of the submitted text. You can provide a min / max length of the substrings, allowing you to tweak the length of the tokens generated.

If your input is just the single string you want to search substrings of, use a `KeywordTokenizer` - this will keep your input string as a single token, which then is used to [generate the substrings with the NgramFilter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-N-GramFilter):

```
<filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory"/>
```

The default values for min/max is 1 and 2, which gives (from the examples):

```
In: "four score"
Tokenizer to Filter: "four", "score"
Out: "f", "o", "u", "r", "fo", "ou", "ur", "s", "c", "o", "r", "e", "sc", "co", "or", "re"
```

In your case the whole string would be kept as a single value, so you'd have "four score" instead of to separate tokens.

The example given for 1 / 4 in values in the example on the wiki currently is wrong (seems it has been copied from the EdgeNGramFilter), so ignore that.

You'll need to tweak the min/max values depending on how you're going to query the content. If you're never going to query for a substring less than three in length, use 3 as the minimum value.

Comment: Thanks so much. The explanations are very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a specific analysis chain for your use case :

```
<fieldType name="text_ngram" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        ...
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="4"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt" />
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

N.B. at query time, don't do any Ngram token filtering, if you don't want unexpected behaviours.

[1] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-N-GramFilter